# Facebook Comment widget returns "Content no longer available"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Following the upgrade from Graph 1.0 to Graph 2.0 the comment widgets have stopped working for me, returning the following JSON response following any attempt to post a comment:

```
{
    bootloadable: {}
    error: 1357031
    errorDescription: "The content you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may have expired, or you may not have permission to view this page."
    errorSummary: "This content is no longer available"
    ixData: {}
    lid: "0"
    payload: null
}
```

I've been through the steps so far of regenerating the comment code, making sure the comment block code itself is set to use version 2.3 (as well as trying without this just to be safe).  The error code itself doesn't return anything in the FB docs, and the only reference I can find to the error description is from 2 years ago to which FB noted that it was a server issue.  Given that our comments have been broken (and thus hidden) for 2 months now I don't think that's the problem.

I've confirmed that the code pulls in sdk.js rather than all.js using the code they provide and I just can't seem to get it to work.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you have tried to re-upload these files?

```
admin.css
class-admin.php
class-fronted.php
facebook-comments.php
```